# Parsing a complex table structure

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse with C#

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|      1      |                                         2                                         |        3       |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 000         | Собственные средства (капитал), итого,                                            |                |
|             | в том числе:                                                                      |     1024231079 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100         |Источники базового капитала:                                                       |     1291298211 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.1       |Уставный капитал кредитной организации:                                            |      651033884 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.1.1     |сформированный обыкновенными акциями                                               |      129605413 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.1.2     |сформированный привилегированными акциями                                          |      521428471 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.1.3     |сформированный долями                                                              |              0 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.2       |Эмиссионный доход:                                                                 |      439401101 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 100.2.1     |кредитной организации в организационно-правовой форме акционерного общества, всего,|                |
|             | в том числе:                                                                      |      439401101 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

My code is

```
string[] dels = { "\r\n" };
string[] strArr = someStr.Split(dels, StringSplitOptions.None);

Console.WriteLine(strArr);

foreach (String sourcestring in strArr)
{
    if (sourcestring != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing string: ");
        Console.WriteLine(sourcestring);
        //Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\|)(.*)(\|)(.*[а-я]{3}.*)(\|)(.*\d+.*)(\|)(.*[\d+|Х].*)(\|)(.*[\d+|Х].*)(\|)(.*\d+.*)(\|)$");
        //Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\|)(\s?|\d+[\.?])(\|)(.*[а-я]{3}.*)(\|)(.*\d+.*)(\|)(.*[\d+|Х].*)(\|)(.*[\d+|Х].*)(\|)(.*\d+.*)(\|)$");
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\|)(\d+\.?\d+)");
        MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(sourcestring);
        int mIdx = 0;
        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, regex.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
            }
            mIdx++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

I need to extract values of lines

```
4 - ' 000         ', ' Собственные средства (капитал), итого,                                            ', '                '

5 - '             ', ' в том числе:                                                                      ', '     1024231079 '
```

and line 7, 9...

The main issue now it that I don't know how to make reg exp to find in the first column values, that could be:

```
' 000         '

'             '

' 100         '

' 100.1       '

' 100.1.1     '
```

and etc.

The second issue is in the second column. I've tried to parse it with the `(.*[а-я]{3}.*)`, but it failed on lines, which contain such symbols, like `'('`, `','`, `'.'`, `':'`.

I'll appreciate all possible solutions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with RegEx? Seems like overkill to me to be honest. With all the pipes `|` a simple split and trim would certainly be easier and faster.

Comment: first step could be matching each Column value: ```\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [RegEx would be overkill in this case](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/), a simple, manual parse approach would be a lot easier:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Two approaches that might work in this case:

1. Parse the first line (`+---+--- ...`) to determine the length of each column and parse your data by separation it with `Substring`.
2. Split each column by `|`.

Below, I've outlines the basics for the second approach (No sanity checks).
If your data can contain `|` too, you might want to parse the data based on cell-size rather than splitting by it.

```cs
// Row is defined below - simple data storage for three the columns
List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
Row currentRow = null;

// Process each line
foreach (string line in input.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    // Row separator or content?
    if (line.StartsWith("+"))
    {
        if (currentRow != null)
        {
            rows.Add(currentRow);
            currentRow = null;
        }
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("|"))
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] {'|'});
        if(currentRow == null)
            currentRow = new Row();

        // Might need additional processing
        currentRow.Column1 += parts[1].Trim();
        currentRow.Column2 += parts[2].TrimEnd();
        currentRow.Column3 += parts[3].TrimStart();
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid data?
    }
}

// Show result
foreach(Row row in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", row.Column1, row.Column2, row.Column3);
}
```

Instead of a custom class you could of course use a `Tuple<string,string,string>` or whatever fits your data types.

```cs
public class Row
{
    public string Column1 = "";
    public string Column2 = "";
    public string Column3 = "";
}
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/hwFohy)